# how to serve static html in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat7

i'm new to spring boot.I want to static serve html file from one of the method.I tried multiple examples but i'm stucked 
Here is my java files

```
package project;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class Example1{

    @RequestMapping("/getHtml")
    public String serve(){
        System.out.println("Served");
        return "eg1.html";
    }
}
```

i have deployed this application on tomcat as a war file.I have placed eg1.html in src\main\resources\

Edit:
I'm getting this as error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14SOf.jpg]

Comment: tried but didnt worked

Comment: why is your html file in `src\main\resources` and  what configuration did you provide to the view resolver

Comment: this one System.out.println("Served"); works ??

Comment: no..it didnt worked either

Comment: I thought the default location for static content was `src/main/resources/static`. Check out https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: i want to make one thing clear..i'm fairly new to spring boot..it will be great help for me if someone guide me how to send static html file in spring boot

Comment: I had used gradle

Comment: ok show your gradle file

Comment: i have uploaded error message @georgesvan

Comment: i have found the solution,i just added my eg1.html in src/main/resouces/static .It finally worked

Comment: Suggest to start with the documentation. Serving static content -> have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: you can't serve same name file as root if exist a file in static folder because it is automatically mapped from spring